Is there a universal state machine or petri net model that covers all possible BPMN paths?
I am working on developing a BPMN chatbot and need a comprehensive solution to model all possible BPMN paths. Specifically, I'm looking for an existing state machine or Petri net implementation that can represent every BPMN element and process in a general-purpose manner. I am familiar with some of the work of van der Aalst on this area.
Does anyone know of any tools, libraries, or frameworksthat provide such a universal solution for BPMN processes? Any pointers or resources would be incredibly helpful!
Thank you!
I have tried modelling the chatbot without formal verification and that ended up in incomplete paths for the BPMN.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is a straight-forward translation of the control flow perspective of a basic BPMN diagram into a labelled Petri net.
You can find some examples in Chapter 8 of the "Prozessmanagement und Process-Mining" Book of Koschmieder, Laue, and Fahland.
There is also a lecture by Prof. Dr. Mathias Weske, available online describing the basic concepts.
